# How to get all items in SC with a specific content type using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, search, search-results, item, search-query

There are five custom lists in a site collection, all have same content type. I would like to get all items from those five lists using JavaScript. Is there a way to get all items from all lists having a specific content type using JavaScript?

This is my code:

```
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var hostweburl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPHostUrl"));
var parentContext = new SP.AppContextSite(clientContext, hostweburl);
var parentWeb = parentContext.get_web();
var listCollection = parentWeb.get_lists();
var list;
var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var user = context.get_web().get_currentUser();

$(document).ready(function () {
context.load(listCollection);
context.load(user);

function onGetUserNameSuccess() {
    Filter()
}
function onGetUserNameFail(sender, args) {
    message("Failed to get user name. Error:" + args.get_message(), "danger", "glyphicon glyphicon-remove");
}
context.executeQueryAsync(onGetUserNameSuccess, onGetUserNameFail)
});

function getQueryStringParameter(paramToRetrieve) {

var params = document.URL.split("?")[1].split("&");
var strParams = "";

for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i = i + 1) {

    var singleParam = params[i].split("=");

    if (singleParam[0] == paramToRetrieve) {
        return singleParam[1];
    }
}
}

function Filter() {

var listString = "";
var listEnumerator1 = listCollection.getEnumerator();
while (listEnumerator1.moveNext()) {
    var currentItm = listEnumerator1.get_current();
    listString = currentItm.get_title();

    var query = new SP.CamlQuery();
    query.set_viewXml("<View><Query><Where><And><Eq><FieldRef Name='Author'             /><Value Type='User'>" + user.get_title() + "</Value></Eq><Eq><FieldRef Name='ContentType' /><Value Type='Computed'>Nintex</Value></Eq></And></Where></Query></View>");

    var items = listCollection.getByTitle(listString).getItems(query);
    clientContext.load(items);

    function onSuccess() {
        var itmString = "";
        var enumerator = items.getEnumerator();

        while (enumerator.moveNext()) {
            var currentItem = enumerator.get_current();
            var id = currentItem.get_id();
            itmString += "<div class='alert alert-danger divHeader' data-id='" + id + "' innerHTML=<label class='divHeader'>" + currentItem.get_item("Title") + "</label></div><div class='alert alert-warning divContent' id='" + id + "' style= 'display: none;' ></div>";
        }
        $("#minaBlanketter").html(itmString);
    }

    function onFail(sender, args) {
        message("Error:" + args.get_message(), "danger", "glyphicon glyphicon-remove");
    }

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onSuccess, onFail);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can leverage SharePoint search APIs to get all the items.
Pre-Requisites:

1. Search configured with continuous crawl enabled.

You can use either Search REST APIs or KQL in JSOM.

**REST API:**

```
  function getSearchResultsREST(queryText) {
    var url = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/search/query?querytext='" + queryText + "'";
    var executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl);
    executor.executeAsync(
        {
            url: url,
            method: "GET",
            headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
            success: function (data) {/*Parse the data object to get your result */ },
            error: function (err) { alert(JSON.stringify(err)); }
        }
    );
}
```

**JSOM:**

```
function getSearchResultsJSOM(queryText)
{
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var contextSite = clientContext.get_site();
    var keywordQuery = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Search.Query.KeywordQuery(clientContext);
    keywordQuery.set_queryText(queryText);
    var searchExecutor = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Search.Query.SearchExecutor(clientContext);
    var results = searchExecutor.executeQuery(keywordQuery);
    context.executeQueryAsync(function (data) { /*Parse the data object to get your result */ }, function (err) { });
}
```

Now your query text will be something like :

```
ContentTypeID:<ID Of CType1> OR ContentTypeID:<ID Of CType2> OR ContentTypeID:<ID Of CType3 > OR ContentTypeID:<ID Of CType4> OR ContentTypeID:<ID Of CType5 >
```

Comment: Thank you very much Unnie for you kindly answer but this is the first time i use the search Query in JSOM and i need some more help please. if  I have a div in HTML with id "allItmes". How can i print all the items title in this div in the JSOM methos

Comment: I mean what im gonna write in that Place you have worte /*Parse the data object to get your result */

Comment: http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2013/01/calling-sharepoint-search-using-rest-eg.html  See this blog. Look at the success callback method where the JSON is parsed. Also look for samples on how to parse json